# Access denied for all users

Tags: sharepoint

In SharePoint foundation all user can not access the site even site owner. I am getting Access denied error for all users. How can we resolve this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Check if site collection admin is able to log in.

Comment: The site admin is also not able to login